# Comparison based sorting is WC min time nlogn, so what about best/average case

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree, graph-theory, binary-search

There is a theorem in Cormen which says...
(Th 8.1)
"For comparison based sorting techniques you cannot have an algorithm to sort a given list, which takes time less than nlogn time (comparisons) in the worst case"
I.e. 
the *worst case* time complexity is *Omega* (nlogn) for *Comparison based sorting technique...*

Now  what I was searching is that whether there exists a statement in case of the best case..or even for avg case
Which states something like:

> You cannot have a sorting Algorithm which takes time less than some X to sort a given list of elements...in the best case

Basically do we have any lower bound for best case Algorithm. Or even as a matter of fact for average case. (I tried my best to find this, but couldn't find anywhere). Please also tell me whether the point I am raising is even worth it.

Comment: You should be able to reason about the best case scenario for some of these algorithms (hint: can you determine if an array is sorted without at least _looking_ at all elements?), but a more comprehensive list [is given on the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms).

Comment: @N.Wouda so you mean to say that we can't formally define a statement as we did for Worst case ..?

Comment: Any comparison-based sorting algorithm can be prefaced with code to check whether the array is already sorted. That check is typically a waste of time, but won't affect the theoretical time complexity of the algorithm. So the best case time for comparison-based sorts is the time to check whether an array is already sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! The challenge with defining “average case” complexity is that you have to ask “averaged *over what?*”

For example, if we assume that the elements of the array have an equal probability of being in any one of the n! possible permutations of n elements, then the Ω(n log n) bound on comparison sorting still holds, though I seem to remember that the proof of this is fairly complicated.

On the other hand, if we assume that there are trends in the data (say, you’re measuring temperatures over the course of a day, where you know they generally trend upward and then downward). Many real world data sets look like this, and there are algorithms like Timsort that can take advantage of those patterns to speed up performance. So perhaps “average” here would mean “averaged over all possible plots formed by a rising and then falling sequence with noise terms added in.” I haven’t encountered anyone working on analyzing algorithms in those cases, but I’m sure some work has been done there and there may even be some nice average case measures there that are less well known.

Comment: First of all thanks for an answer. But does that mean it's Omega nlogn in best and avg case both?

Comment: Bcoz in that book of Cormen, the proof goes by taking into account that n! Leaves and so they should be less than 2^h and thus h cannot be greater than nlogn..? But I am unable to even think of a way how should we even proceed for best/avg case calculation..and would it be the same answer or something else..bcoz anyway in a strict Binary Tree half of the nodes  would still be at leaf level so complexity would be logn for them..thus making total about Order of nlogn...(I can be wrong in this.plz correct)

Comment: Assuming we’re dealing with truly random permutations, yes, both the average and worst case performance of any sorting algorithm must be at least Omega(n log n).